# How many combinations am I truly offering?

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently running a promotion for my company and we would like to truly explain how many combinations exist for the product.  Here is how the steps break down:

- Step $1:$ Customer orders Rice or Salad version
- Step $2:$ Customer orders a protein: Chicken, Taco Beef, Steak or Veggie
- Step $3:$ Customer orders beans: black beans, pinto beans, refried beans (customer may order no beans, 1 bean, 2 beans, all bean options)
- Step $4:$ Add any or all of these toppings: Shredded Cheese, Pico, Romaine Lettuce Mix, Grilled Onions/Peppers, Fiesta Corn Salsa, Chipotle Citrus Vinaigrette, or Creamy Jalapeno Ranch.
- Step $5:$ Add any or all of these toppings: Crumbled bacon, Guacamole, Sour Cream, Queso.

Comment: Can you solve simpler related problems? For example, if you offered option 1 or option 2, and then option A or option B, how many options would there be?

Comment: This question has made me hungry :(

Comment: Some of these combinations might be isomorphic. Is the cheese in step 4 different from the queso in step 5?

Comment: Does "any or all" choices out of $n$ mean that the number of toppings chosen must be either $1$ or $n$, as a strict interpretation would suggest? And if the more lenient interpretation of "any subset" is applied, why separate steps $4$ and $5$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  For each of the first two steps, the customer chooses one of a list, so you multiply the number of options at each step.  For the last three steps, you can make each item into a separate step and the choice is yes or no.  How many options is that?

Answer (score 1):

Below, the $\binom{n}{k}$ notation refers to choose, which tells you the number of ways you can choose $k$ items from a collection of $n$.

Step 1: 2 choices.

Step 2: 4 choices.

Step 3: It's the number of ways to choose $0$ items from $3$, plus the number of ways to choose $1$ item from $3$, etc.... $\binom{3}{0} + \binom{3}{1} +\binom{3}{2} +\binom{3}{3} = 8$ choices

Step 4: Similar to step 3, there are 7 items, you can choose between 0 and 7 of them, so there are $\sum_{k=0}^{7} \binom{7}{k} = 2^7 = 128$ choices.

Step 5: There are 4 items and you can choose between 0 and 4 of them, so there are 
$\sum_{k=0}^{4} \binom{4}{k} = 2^4 = 16$ choices

For the total number of combos you multiply these numbers together, so there are $2\cdot 4 \cdot 8 \cdot 128 \cdot 16 = 2^{17} = 131072$ total combos.

Comment: It might be good to point out that this works out the same as the simpler method in the other answer because $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, status update: I just went and told a fellow student about this wonderful fact you've revealed to me. He really liked it. We're going to go talk about it some more. Thanks again!

Comment: @TrevorWilson, we chatted about it for a while and I think we just proved that $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k$!!! :-) BTW, re your comment above: queso is a condiment found frequently at mexican restaurants. It's a kind of liquid cheese whiz mixed with salsa kind of thing and it is distinct from regular cheese so the two are quite different I think.

Comment: [I have deleted my earlier comments, which were totally off the mark.  It seems that I confused the "factorial" symbol with some punctuation indicating enthusiasm for the binomial theorem.  How embarrassing!]

Comment: @TrevorWilson, I'm an enthusiastic chap. That clears everything up!